# How to install ibicui18n.so.55

Tags: r

I was trying to install a 'qgraph' R package in RStudio when the erros happens: libicui18n.so.55: Unable to open shared object file: File or directory not found.

Somebody would help how to fix this problem ?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

The particular file that you are looking for is found in the [package libicu55](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libicui18n.so.55) in the Xenial archives.  It does not appear in the Trusty or Zesty archives, however.

If you are running Xenial, you will be able to install this with `sudo apt install libicu55`

Comment: I think I have a backport of this file somewhere in a PPA... I'll have to check.